# Varnish or Squid - Which is Good for web cache in small office?

Tags: networking, squid, varnish

First, I am not sure if Varnish can be used as web-cache to speedup internet in small offices.

We have an office with 20 systems around and we frequently browse same set of websites.

I setup squid and it worked fine for sometime. But I couldn't get to cache youtube videos which was my main aim.

I came recently across Varnish while playing with nginx but I see it is being used as web-accelerator for backend server.

Can we use Varnish instead of nginx for web-cache in transparent way?
I mean to say that people in my office will not need to configure proxy on their machine.

Thanks,

-Rahul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Varnish really isn't meant to be a general purpose web cache like Squid. From the [Varnish FAQ](http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/FAQ#DoesthatmeanIcantuseVarnishasaforwardproxy):

> **Does that mean I can't use Varnish as a forward proxy?**
> You can, but you probably don't want to. Doing it requires significant amounts of DNS magic and a huge Varnish VCL file.

You *can* configure squid as a [transparent proxy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html) (on Windows you need some third-party software to handle what iptables does on Linux) and alleviate the need to configure PCs to use the proxy.

Caching YouTube videos is a pain, irrespective of the transparency of the proxy. You can read about [some of the problems caching YouTube content](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube) and see possible "workarounds" that may or may not work for you (or may stop working if YouTube makes changes).

Comment: Thanks Evan. :-)
I am already running squid in transparent proxy mode using iptables. I guess I better put more efforts in squid for youtube issue rather than looking for alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to jump in. Try using Lusca (a fork of the Squid-2 development tree), and for the video's http://cachevideos.com/. It's really works on me.